# How do I fix it? What do I need to study?

Tags: java

I'm studying Java, I want to know what to do.
How do I fix it? What do I need to study?
I do not understand how to use methord. Two types [image]

[image]

Comment: Code is text. Please include it in your question as text, not as images.

Answer (score 1):

In this example your mistake is calling both methods at the same time.

```
System.out.print(setName("tine") + " " + setLastname("Linux"));
```

As a future reference I don't think you should use set functions to return value. Those should be void and then you can use get methods to return.

```
public static String getName(){
   return name;
}
```

Comment: Your second code block won't compile. Look at your return type.

Comment: Thanks @ImpulseTheFox. Guess my mind was stuck on the void part :)

Answer (score 1):

There is so much wrong here.

- Setter methods, as `setName` and `setLastname` should not just return the parameter. Instead, as the name suggets, set something.
- Your setters methods are static, but your members `name` and `lastName` are not. This is not possible, your setter methods should not be static.
- At `System.out.println("tine",setLastName("linux"));` you call the `setName` method with two parameters (a String "tine" and the result of `setLastName("linux")` which is just "linux"), but it expects only one parameter.
- Your ClassB class should have getters, if it has setters.
- Don't name your method `getPrint` if it doesn't get something.

Your code should look like this:

```
public class ClassA extends ClassB
{
    public void print()
    {
        setName("tine");
        setLastname("linux");
        System.out.println(getName() + " " + getLastname());
    }
}
```

```
public class ClassB
{
    String name;
    String lastname;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastname()
    {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname)
    {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

Now you can call `new ClassA().print();` somewhere in your code and it will print: `tine linux`.

Answer (score 0):

You should really learn how functions work in general. Also how OOP (Object Oriented Programming) works. [Wikipedia on OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

Answer (score -2):

Try instead of 
`System.out.println(setName("tine") + setLastName("linux"));`

Comment: This doesn't compile - it's not valid Java